# how to store data in Firebase with serial numbers?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an Android application. I want to store some user's data in Firebase with serial numbers. The serial number should auto-increment when a user is added and even if a user is deleted, the flow of numbers should be maintained.
[image: This is just an edited image to show an example of how I want the data.]